# SQL Server - use case statement within group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, view, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a view as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW vw1 AS SELECT     
  Town
, case when (Spend > 0 and NbOrders > 0)
       then sum(Spend)/sum(NbOrders)
       else null
       end as AvgSpend
, case when (Margin > 0 and NbOrders > 0)
       then sum(Margin)/sum(NbOrders)
       else null
       end as AvgMargin
FROM Table
group by Town
```

But I get an error because the fields used in my 'case when...' statement aren't included in an aggregate function.

I can't use a 'where' clause because the average fields depend on different fields being >0 and I can't see how I could make the case when work on an aggregated field?

Any ideas how I can achieve this - preferably in a single statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated... thanks to @Andriy M

```
SELECT town

,SUM(CASE WHEN Spend > 0 and NbOrders > 0 THEN Spend END)
/SUM(CASE WHEN Spend > 0 and NbOrders > 0 THEN NbOrders END)  As AvgSpend

,SUM(CASE WHEN Margin > 0 and NbOrders > 0 THEN Margin END)
/ SUM(CASE WHEN Margin > 0 and NbOrders > 0 THEN NbOrders END) As AvgMargin

FROM table
GROUP BY town
```

Comment: In general I would recommend something similar to: SUM(CASE WHEN...THEN...ELSE...END)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW vw1 AS
SELECT
  Town
, SUM(CASE WHEN Spend > 0 THEN Spend END)
  / SUM(CASE WHEN NbOrders > 0 THEN NbOrders END) AS AvgSpend
, SUM(CASE WHEN Margin > 0 THEN Margin END)
  / SUM(CASE WHEN NbOrders > 0 THEN NbOrders END) AS AvgMargin
FROM Table
GROUP BY Town
```

Comment: this what i meant by saying simplifying the code, but I have a little doubt

Comment: @niktrs: In this particular case neither of the SUMs can ever be 0. If, for instance, there are no positive `Spend` values, the corresponding SUM() will return NULL.

Comment: Thanks Andriy, but I don't think this is quite right as, for example, `SUM(CASE WHEN Spend > 0 THEN Spend END)` will include rows where NbOrders is not > 0.

Comment: @dan: Ah, I can see now, in both both cases both conditions are mandatory for each of the SUMs. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to include the `group by` in each "case".

something like the below:

```
CREATE VIEW vw1 AS SELECT     
  Town
, case when (Spend > 0 and NbOrders > 0)
       then sum(Spend)/sum(NbOrders)
       group by Town
       else null
       end as AvgSpend
, case when (Margin > 0 and NbOrders > 0)
       then sum(Spend)/sum(NbOrders)
       group by Town
       else null
       end as AvgMargin
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW vw1 AS SELECT     
  Town
, case when (Spend > 0 and NbOrders > 0)
       then sum(Spend)/sum(NbOrders)
       else null
       end as AvgSpend
, case when (Margin > 0 and NbOrders > 0)
       then sum(Spend)/sum(NbOrders)
       else null
       end as AvgMargin
FROM Table
group by Town, AvgSpend, AvgMargin
```